# Adding text from mySQL query onto canvas

Tags: php, mysql, canvas

In this code, I successfully get five random text strings from a mySQL database, and can echo them via PHP.

Instead of echoing them via PHP, I would rather like to display them as text in the canvas (in place of the "Hello World" text) of the attached code.

Any ideas of how I would have to go about doing this?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
</script>

<?PHP
    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','','');
    //select database
    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'test')) {
        echo "database not selected";
    }
    //select query
    //select random question
    $sql=   
        "select * from `general knowledge`
        order by rand()
        limit 5";
    //execute sql query
    $records= (mysqli_query($con,$sql));
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
            echo "<P>";
            echo "".$row['Question Text']."";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your PHP code block before the HTML block, and then change the loop you have by this:

```
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
        $questions[] = $row['Question Text'];
    }
```

This just puts the 5 questions in an array called *$questions*.

Then when you generate the HTML, you can do things like this:

```php
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[4]?>",10,50);
</script>
```

Notice the injection of a PHP value with the `<?=    ?>` tag. You can then inject any one of the five questions. For instance like this:

```
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[0]?>",10,50);
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[1]?>",20,50);
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[2]?>",30,50);
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[3]?>",40,50);
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[4]?>",50,50);
```

If you really want to have a loop for this (is it really that useful?), you could write one in PHP:

```
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
<?php
foreach ($questions as $index => $question) {
     echo "    ctx.fillText('$question', 10+$index*10, 50);\n";
}
?>
</script>
```

You'll need to adapt the factor (it is now 10) with which you would multiply *$index* to get the right vertical distance between your texts.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I know the next step is to build in some for loops to increment the question as well as the position where it is displayed.  So far I've just tried this around the code that displays the question (it didn't work!): for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
    ctx.fillText("<?= $questions[i]?>",10,65);
}

Comment: Well the loop would have to be generated by PHP, but before I add that to my answer: you don't really want to put the 5 texts at the same position, right?

Comment: aha!  so you'd need a loop in PHP code for the question number, incrementing by 1 and another loop incrementing by e.g. 12 for the position in the box. :) time to read up on some PHP!

Comment: I added some suggestions to my answer. Like often, there are many ways to do this. Mixing PHP with HTML can be done in several ways. Here I opted for doing `echo` of HTML inside a PHP loop.

Comment: yes, it worked perfectly, thanks! :) for now I'm using them without the loop, as per your first suggestion.  I will ultimately have more than five questions and thought about having them scroll over the canvas and thus loop and increment the position where they are displayed.